# Revert Erlang OTP Version

Tags: upgrade, 14.04, versions

I have upgraded my ubuntu to latest version. This automatically updated my `erlang version` from `5.10.2` to `5.10.4` i.e `OTP 16R01 to OTP 16R03`

```
$ erl +V
Erlang (SMP,ASYNC_THREADS) (BEAM) emulator version 5.10.4
```

Here is my updated ubuntu details :

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Since the project is throwing error :

```
,{badarg,[{erlang,halt,[1,"Chicago Boss is not comptable with 16R03"],[]}
```

Is there any way to revert my otp version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will probably need to compile from source.
Uninstall the current version
Then compile and install from source
Steps as follows:

Remove Erlang Completely

```
sudo apt-get purge erlang*
```

Update missings if required

```
sudo apt-get --fix-missing -y install build-essential m4 libncurses5-dev libssh-dev unixodbc-dev libgmp3-dev libwxgtk2.8-dev libglu1-mesa-dev fop xsltproc default-jdk`
```

Download requird OTP version:

```
wget http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_R16B01.tar.gz 
tar -xvzf otp_src_R16B01.tar.gz 
sudo chmod -R 777 otp_src_R16B01 
cd otp_src_R16B01 
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

And you will be ready :)
cheers